# Is it possible to include two variables for locations in GeoJSON

Tags: python, plotly, geojson, choropleth

I want to include both lng and lat for locations as the coordinates for a choropleth map, is there way to do this?

Here is the code I have:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv')

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Choroplethmapbox(
        geojson= "city.geojson",
        featureidkey = "properties.city",
        locations = df["ZIP"], #lng lat
        z = df["data"],
        zauto = True,
        colorscale = "Viridis",
        showscale = True,
    )
```

I changed some of the variables and the csv file as I don't want to share the entirety of the code. I currently only have the zip code as the locations only take one column of data.

*I apologize if this question does not make sense, I normally don't use GeoJSON or Plotly. So I can try to explain more to the best of my ability if needed

Comment: usually without posting an actual attempt, you will not get a useful solution, and more likely will be downvoted and closed

Comment: Can you include both as parameters in your HTTP request? What does the documentation say for the API you're using?

Comment: I recommend adding some code to your question and illustrating by an example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the code to it now, sorry about that.

Comment: The data you want to plot should be passed to the `geojson` parameter as GeoJSON obects.  `locations` has another purpose.

Comment: @TimRoberts, would I be able to pass the lng and lat data through with the geojson map ("city.geojson") I have included? I apologize if I am explaining this wrong, I haven't used Plotly or geojson before so I am still learning as I apply it.

Comment: I think the [examples](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/#choropleth-map-using-plotlygraphobjects-and-carto-base-map-no-token-needed) in the references will serve your purpose, so please refer to them

Comment: I don't know what you think "city.geojson" is doing, but it's not doing anything.  The `geojson` parameter has to be either a data structure containing your GeoJSON data, or a URL where it can fetch the data.  `geojson` is neither of those things.